# Why is it that: "If polynomials have integer coefficients, the roots of those polynomials will be a divisor (factor) of the constant term"?

Tags: functions, polynomials, proof-explanation, roots

So, in my textbook, I came across a theorem/axiom (?) that states:

> Given a polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients, its roots, if they exist, are divisors of the independent/constant term of the polynomial

I've wrapped my head around this and I can't figure out why. There's a explanation in my book, but I can't quite understand it. It goes like this:

> Given a polynomial $P(x)$ with whole numbers as coefficients

> $P(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$    and  $a$  is an integer root of $P(x)$ , then  $a$  is a divisor of $a_{_{0}}$ (the independent term).

> **Demonstration:**

> $$P(a)=a_{n}a^n+a_{n-1}a^{n-1}\dots+a_{1}a+a_{0}=0$$

> From here, it results that:

> $$a_{0}=a_{n}a^n-a_{n-1}a^{n-1}-_{\dots}-a_{1}a$$
> Therefore, $a_{0}$ is a multiple of $a$  , i. e. $a$ is a divisor of $a_{0}$ .

Can someone explain to me why this is true? And maybe give a real example with a polynomial.

Thanks.

Comment: What part of that argument do you not follow?

Comment: Also, this only holds for the integer roots.

Comment: @Randall To begin with. I'm not even sure of what $a_{n-1}$ means or, what the $n-1$ is trying t convey, below in $a_{n-1}$ , for example.

Comment: Those are just labels for the coefficients.  So in $f(x)=3x^2-4x+2$ we have $a_2=3, a_1=-4, a_0=2$.

Comment: @Randall well yes, but with $a_{n}x^{n}$  and $a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ it seems that those "labels" tell us that there's some kind of relationship with the exponent

Comment: The relationship is that the subscript on the label matches the exponent.  That's it.

Comment: You may be interested in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: For example if $P(x) =27x^5 + 32x^4-19x^3 + 5x + 1$ then the coefficients are, from left to right, are:  $27, 32, -19, 0, 5$, and $1$ and we label them.  $a_5$ is the label for the $x^5$ term.  $a_5 = 27$.  $a_4$ is the label for the $x^4$ term.  $a_4=32$. $a_3$ is the label for the $x^3$ term.  $a_3 =-19$.  $a_2$ is the label for the $x^2$ term.  $a_2=0$. And $a_1$ is the label for the $x=x^1$ term. $a_1 = 5$ and finally $a_0$ is the label for the constant ($x$ to the zeroth power) term and $a_0=1$.  That's *all* it is.

Comment: It's kind of the same as $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ or $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ but we just don't know how many letters we need.

Comment: "it seems that those "labels" tell us that there's some kind of relationship with the exponent"  The relation is called "indexing" and that's what it is.  The coefficient of the $x^{37}$ term is the $37$th (after $0$) to be indexed with the term $a_{37}$.  Indexing *is* a relationship but its a very basic and simple one.  $a_k$ is the coefficient of the $x^k$ term.  There's no formula or calculations other than "$x^k$ is the $k$th power and $a_k$ is the $k$th (non-constant) coefficient".  That's the entirity of the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The argument presented in the body of your question is perfectly sound [with a missing minus sign:  a typo?] and is worth digesting.  If you find that *the notation* is what's holding you back, then write out the entire argument in **one special case** but with different notation until you believe in it.  This will make understanding the full result easier.

Let's argue this for quadratics only, so assume $P(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ where $a, b, c$ are all integers.  Suppose $r$ is an integer root.  Then
$$
P(r) = ar^2 + br + c =0
$$
and so
$$
c = -ar^2 - br = r(-ar -b).
$$
It is now clear that $r$ is a divisor of $c$, the constant term.

Understanding this, it is not hard to extract the fully general argument for a polynomial of degree $n$.  After all, the argument you've presented does the *exact same thing*, just with more terms and more generality.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathit F(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$, where $\mathit a_n, a_{n-1}, \dots, a_0$ are all arbitrary integer coefficients.

$\it Note:$ $\;$The subscripts $\mathit n, n-1$, etc. don't mean that there's any relation between the coefficient and the power of each term, but rather just a convenient way of naming coefficients of polynomials of large degree instead of using all the letters of the alphabet or something along those lines.

Suppose r is an integral root of $\mathit F(x)$,
$$\mathit \implies a_nr^n + a_{n-1}r^{n-1} + \dots + a_1r + a_0 = 0$$
$$\mathit \iff -a_nr^n - a_{n-1}r^{n-1} - \dots - a_1r = a_0$$
$$\mathit \iff r(-a_nr^{n-1} - a_{n-1}r^{n-2} - \dots - a_1) = a_0$$
$$\mathit \iff r\,|\, a_0$$

I'll give an example of a quadratic to clear up any confusion.

$$\mathit P(x) = x^2 + 8x + 7$$
$$\mathit P(x) = (x + 7)(x + 1)$$
$\mathit \implies x = -7$ and $\mathit x = -1$ are roots, which are factors of the constant term, i.e. 7.

Hopefully that helped clear up any confusion you had! You may want to check out something called the [Rational Roots Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which is essentially a more generalised case of this theorem that extends across the rational numbers instead of just the integers.